# While using Selelnium, i'm getting an error

Tags: java, selenium, netbeans

I downloaded the standalone server file, the driver file, then copied to the Library. I already moved the "lib" folder in the selenium file to the Library location also. Here's the code

```
    package google.search;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class GoogleSearch {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new WebDriver object (Firefox browser)
WebDriver bot = new HtmlUnitDriver();

// Navigating to google.com
bot.get("http://www.google.com");

// Find the text input element by its name
WebElement inputField = bot.findElement(By.name("q"));

// Send some keys into the textfield
inputField.sendKeys("Selenium is easy");

// Submit your text (to start a google search)
inputField.submit();

// Saving the page source code into a string
String pageSource = bot.getPageSource();

//Closing the Firefox browser and "shutdown" the WebDriver object
bot.quit();
    }

}
```

Even now that I get no red error indicators, I still get this weird error that I never encountered before. can someone tell me what this means?

```
Feb 21, 2015 1:02:49 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLElement addBehavior
WARNING: Unimplemented behavior: #default#userdata
```

Answer (score 4):

You can  add BrowserVersion class object for an HtmlUnitDriver to remove this error as

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
```

The object name can be replaced by different respective names.This is also different than creating a browser specific driver e.g. FirefoxDriver()